# Stripes: all URLs resolved through StripesDispatcher and forwarded to pre-compiled JSPs

Tags: url, servlets, web.xml, stripes, urlbinding

Is it possible to have the StripesDispatcher be the sole determiner of webserver urls by looking at the @UrlBinding annotations on action beans AND also having those action beans forward to pre-compiled JSPs / servlets WITHOUT needing to define and maintain <servlet> <servlet-mapping> pairs in web.xml? Basically, I just want to have to only maintain the @UrlBinding annotations as the sole determiners of available webapp paths.

Perhaps there is a way to point Jasper to where my servlets are and load them all up automatically without having to explicitly define each and every one?

The particular way in which this is achieved is not important, only that I leave the land of explicit servlet web.xml dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand your question, but I'll give it a go. AFAIK the only mapping you need in a Stripes app's web.xml to use @URLBinding as the 'source of truth' for URLs in your web-app:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ActionResolver.Packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.your.action.beans.package</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>Extension.Packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.your.extension.packages</param-value>
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

...

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

...

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

With this, there is no need to change anything in web.xml when you add/remove action beans and/or JSPs.